# How to add data based on dates?

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

```
10/3/2016   -27
10/3/2016   -2.13
10/3/2016   -12.82
10/3/2016   -7.25
10/3/2016   -4.5
10/3/2016   -19.23
10/3/2016   -1.93
10/3/2016   -10.7
10/3/2016   -63.08
10/3/2016   -12.82
10/3/2016   -10.6
10/3/2016   -14.72
10/3/2016   -14.96
10/4/2016   -152.5
10/4/2016   -6.73
10/4/2016   -12.99
10/4/2016   -4.8
10/4/2016   -16.76
10/4/2016   -8.54
10/4/2016   -7
10/4/2016   27
10/5/2016   93.67
10/6/2016   -8.07
10/7/2016   0.01
10/7/2016   -565.27
10/7/2016   -16.25
10/7/2016   1690.7
```

I have a calendar spreadsheet and I want each date to hold the SUM of all the values for the above.

For example

```
10/1/2016 - $0 (because no data is present)
10/2/2016 - $0
10/3/2016 - (Sum of all dates that are 10/3)
```

I do not know the number of transactions that appear. So there could be 0 or 30.

I am using Excel 2016 (64-bit) on Windows 10 (64-bit)

Comment: You could use a `SUMIF` formula for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter 10/1/2016 in **C1** and `=C1+1` in **C2** and copy down.

Then in **D1** enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A=C1)*(B:B))
```

and copy down:

[image]

If processing is too slow use something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$10000=C1)*($B$1:$B$10000))
```

Comment: why the double --?

Comment: @softwareisfun  To remind me that the expression is an array of **1** and **0**

Answer (score 0):

### SUMIFS

Formula in E2 is: `=SUMIFS($B:$B;$A:$A;D2)`

[image]